# Cartesian product of Vitali set and {0}

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

I am doing a measure theory problem which says:

Let $V$ be the Vitali set in $\mathbb{R}$. Deduce that $E=V \times \lbrace0\rbrace$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but it's not a Borel set.

I think I did well the first part. Let $V$ be a Vitali set. We know that $V \subset [0,1]$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. We can take the rectangle $[0,1] \times (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, which contains $E=V \times \lbrace0\rbrace$, and is measurable. Taking limit when $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, we have a measure $0$ set. Since the Lebesgue measure is complete, every subset of a $0$ measure set has measure $0$, so $E=V \times \lbrace0\rbrace$ is measuable.

My problem is with the second part. I have an idea, but I don't know if it's correct or not:

We know that the Vitali set is not Borel. We can see $E$ as the inverse image of the inclusion of $\mathbb{R}$ in the $X$ axis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is a measurable function. So, I tried the typical proof by contradiction:

Suppose $E=V \times \lbrace0\rbrace$ is Borel. Then, $g^{-1}(E)$ has to be borel. But that is $V$! So $E$ is not Borel.

Is this ok? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why you are using those intervals in the first part. Wouldn't it be simpler to note that $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ (a line segment) is measurable of measure $0$? Both $[0,1]$ and $\{0\}$ are measurable, after all.

Comment: Oh dear you're right. I overcomplicated it. Thanks!

Comment: For the second part, can you edit the question to add an explicit definition of $g$ and explain why $g^{-1}(E)$ has to be measurable if $E$ is Borel?

Comment: I wanted to say "it has to be Borel". Maybe I am wrong, but if I take the embedding of R into the x-axis, the preimage would be Borel, wouldn't it? And so I have the contradiction

Comment: Inverse image of Borel under measurable function is known to be measurable, but not necessarily Borel. So you would want to mention/show that $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $g(x) = (x,0)$ is measurable; then if $E$ is Borel, then it is certainly measurable, so $g^{-1}(E)$ is measurable...